# How to iterate over a filtered dbGrid

Tags: delphi

I have a dbGrid in delphi RAD 10.3. I have a filter applied to only filter 3 of the records persay.

How do I iterate over those 3 records instead of the entire database? Is such a thing even possible?

Regards,
Romans.

Comment: What did you try? Simple loop on all grid rows doesn't work?

Comment: Iterating a DBGrid is the wrong way to think about it!  Just iterate the dataset feeding the grid.  Simples...

Comment: I want to iterate the records that the Table displays in the dbGrid, so i don't see how you are confused.

Comment: Not sure which of us you think is confused, but a DBGrid just shows whatever records the filter on the dataset lets through.  That's why you should think about the dataset, not the DBGrid.  A standard DBGrid is **not** a filtering component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: you can just loop through or iterate like normal. The ADOTable automatically filters the records so that when iterating it only displays those that match the filter.

THIS WILL ONLY HAPPEN IF:

```
Datamodule.ADOTable.filtered := true;
```

Rest of my code:

```
with Datamodule.ADOTable1 do
begin
  DisableControls; //This is to stop the dbGrid from going crazy and showing the iteration.
  First; //Sets first record in the filtered dataset to active record.
  while not Eof do
   begin
     //do your print to screen or whatever you need the data for here. Example
     showmessage(IntToStr(FieldByName('ID').value));
     //this takes the active record's 'ID'-field and prints the value as a showmessage.
     Next; //moves to next record.
   end;
EnableControls;
end;
```

Comment: Your code is wrong! A TDataSource does not have an AdoTable1 property.  It should probably say `with TAdoTable(Datasource1.DataSet) do`.  Please post your actual code, not code you make up from memory when writing the answer ...

Comment: My bad, it should be datamodule, not datasource.

Comment: @Romans I recommend to NOT use the "with" statement.

Comment: Why? I know that it can get confused if you use local variable names like "name", then it will use the `.ADOTable1.Name` instead of what you where intending to use, but other than that it cuts down on typing? Is that a bad thing? Regards.

Comment: "Is that a bad thing?"  The `with` construct the worst mistake in the design of Pascal.  The typing it "saves" is far, far outweighed by the hours people spend looking for the source of subtle errors that `with` permits.  Best to forget that it exists ...

Comment: I have always wished WITH included AS to allow the easy use of short aliases like in SQL. Without it WITH is a bit of a landmine if a lot of similarity named things are in scope.